# Calculate the Transfer Function of an AOP circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, bode-plot

I am trying to calculate the transfer function of this circuit. Does anyone have an idea about it?

[image: schematic]

Image source: [Analog Devices - Circuit Note CN-0276 - part of Figure 2. Excitation Driver and Filter Circuit (All Connections and Decoupling Not Shown)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0276.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does anyone have an idea about it?*

It's a 2nd order multi-feedback low-pass filter followed by a single order RC low-pass filter (cut-off in your image on the right). Together they make a 3rd order low-pass filter. If you want details about the multi-feedback low-pass filter circuit try [Okawa Denshi](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuLowkeisan.htm): -

[image]

[image]

They have a tool that allows you to calculate the resistor and capacitor values to suit a particular cut-off frequency.